# How to exit if statement and continue to else

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a long shot question, but is there a way in php to exit an "if" statement and continue on to the "else" statement if an error occurs inside the if block?

example

```
if ($condition == "good")
{
//do method one

//error occurs during method one, need to exit and continue to else 

}

else 
{
//do method two
}
```

Of course it is possible to do a nested if inside the first if, but that seems hacky.

TIA

Comment: Why is it hacky? If you have a bunch of nested if's it becomes hard to manage, but one or two, not a big deal

Comment: perhaps your looking for a try/catch (exceptions) ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Maybe what your really want is a switch statement.

Comment: yeah, goto should 'solve' that. but i'd just abstract the code in a function and then call it in the else, and in the if, inside a catch{}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
try {
    //do method one

    //error occurs during method one, need to exit and continue to else 
    if ($condition != "good") {
        throw new Exception('foo');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //do method two

}
```

Comment: I think downvote comes from first version of an answer that was like `try ($condition != "good") {` - syntax error

Comment: I upvoted, but still think i should comment that a status flag is a better answer than abusing Exceptions for business logic. @Tomas answer is the one i'd like to see in code i maintain.

Comment: Yea it was a bad copy/paste from the OP's if statement that was up for about 5 seconds before I noticed it. Oh well, you win hasty down-voter :)

Comment: You can't play ignorant, you knew you pasted incorrect code first! "Beats me, I'm curious too :/" that's just silly, huh?

Comment: Thanks Alienguy for the reference.  I will need to modify the code a little, but this is a good place to start.  BTW, this question came about because I am working on a localhost computer and try to bind IP to sockets, but localhost has different IPs thank the public server, so the socket calls will throw errors.  So, I just wanted a good way to switch socket methods if one method fails.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a function so you don't duplicate code:

```
if ($condition == "good") {
    //do method one
    //error occurs during method one
    if($error == true) {
        elsefunction();
    }
} else {
    elsefunction();
}

function elsefunction() {
    //else code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I should do, and the original reason for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Should that be possible? 
Anyway you might consider changing it to.

```
$error = "";
if ($condition == "good") {
 if (/*errorhappens*/) { $error = "somerror"; }
}
if (($condition != "good") || ($error != "") ) {
 //dostuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `methodOne()` such that it returns `true` on success and `false` on error:

```
if($condition == "good" && methodOne()){
  // Both $condition == "good" and methodOne() returned true
}else{
  // Either $condition != "good" or methodOne() returned false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that methodOne returns false on error :

```
if !($condition == "good" && methodOne())
{
//do method two
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you really need this? i think no... but you can hack..

```
do{

   $repeat = false;

   if ($condition == "good")
   {
      //do method one
      $condition = "bad";
      $repeat = true;

    }    
    else 
    {
       //do method two
    }

}while( $ok ) ;
```

I advise on methods to separate...

Answer (score 0):

I find using switches instead of if...else are handy for doing this: Omitting a break statement makes the switch fall through to the next case:

```
switch ($condition) {
case 'good':
    try {
        // method to handle good case.
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // method to handle exception
        // No break, so switch continues to default case.
    }
default:
    // 'else' method
    // got here if condition wasn't good, or good method failed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($condition == "good") {
    try{
        method_1();
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
       method_2();
    }
} 
else {
    method_2();
}

function method_2(){
   //some statement
}
```